# Как отправить сообщение от бота в telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Бот должен каждые несколько секунд отправлять сообщение с текущим временем в свой чат. Но когда сообщение должно отправляться, появляется ошибка:

> aiogram.utils.exceptions.CantTalkWithBots: Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots

```
bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def scheduled(wait_for):
while True:
    await asyncio.sleep(wait_for)

    now = datetime.utcnow()
    await bot.send_message(chat_id, f'{now}', disable_notification=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(scheduled(10))
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Боты не могут слать сообщения ботам, об этом и написано в ошибке

Comment: Вы можете написать боту, так появится приватный чат с ним, где chat_id = ваш user_id, и далее бот сможет уже сам отправлять в этот чат сообщения

Comment: @gil9red Чат с ботом уже есть, я получил от бота ответ на команды, но нужно чтобы он отправлял сообщения сам, помимо ответов на команды.

Comment: Используйте тот `chat_id`, с которым бот имел связь, например, тот с которым у бота есть беседа. Возможно и с групповыми чатами будет работать, если бота добавить (не проверял)